# GXT ComboBox - Use DataGrid Instead of ListView

Tags: gwt, gxt

Is there a way to use a DataGrid instead of a ListView with a comboBox? Is there a way to extend this class? Or use some other component? Or do I have build it from scratch?

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in way to do this - the ComboBox (and the ComboBoxCell) assumes details about the ListView that makes it difficult to just drop in any arbitrary widget like the DataGrid.

That said, there are other options to achieve this. First, consider using a richer cell or template to render your content, giving a grid-like effect, while still using the ListView - the http://www.sencha.com/examples/#ExamplePlace:advancedcombobox example demonstrates this idea with this xtemplate:

```
interface ExampleTemplate extends XTemplates {
  @XTemplate("<div class='{style.searchItem}'>" +
                "<h3>" +
                  "<span>" +
                    "{post.date:date(\"M/d/yyyy\")}" +
                    "<br />" +
                    "by {post.author}" +
                  "</span>" +
                  "{post.title}" +
                "</h3>" +
                "{post.excerpt}" +
              "</div>")
  SafeHtml render(Forum post, ExampleStyle style);
}
```

A second option would be to copy the ComboBoxCell and replace any reference to the ListView with DataGrid, taking special care to correctly manage selection events and any other behavior.

Comment: Is there a way to have an editable checkbox in XTemplates? I found the ListView example that displays an Editable CheckBox (Custom labeled CheckBox Cell, GXT3 guide), but I can't find a way to render more columns. Is there a way to display the checkbox and render multiple columns also? Thank you.

Comment: An xtemplate is just rendered html around some values - you can achieve the same effect with a SafeHtmlBuilder and some Java code. Use whichever approach you like better in a `AbstractCell` implementation, and have that cell's `onBrowserEvent` method handle the clicks and change events to deal with the behavior you expect.